# Do bayesian paired t-tests assume normality?

Tags: bayesian, t-test, paired-data

I'm running a bayesian paired t-test using JASP. In the software, it says that one of the assumptions is that "The difference scores are normally distributed in the population". I'm a little confused as to why this is true since the prior is a Cauchy distribution, not normal. Please let me know if you know why!

Thanks!

Comment: The prior is distribution for the *parameter* (the mean difference), not a model for the observations (the pair-differences). Entirely different things.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. The prior distribution is about where you think the possible values of the parameter (the difference in means) can be. Normality is about the shape of the data distribution in the population or about the distribution of residuals. You can have uniform/half-Cauchy/horse-shoe prior, but that doesn't mean the data are uniform/half-Cauchy/horse-shoe distributed.

In Bayesian analysis (depending on the software), you can change the distribution of residuals from normal to something else, so your Bayesian test doesn't need to assume a normal distribution, but by default, it does, and that is something else than the prior distribution.

This can be done with frequentest/likelihood based analysis too, but it is less common

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.